# Nullpointer Exception when calling a method from Jython

Tags: java, python, nullpointerexception, jython

I am trying to call a function in  my Python module from Java using Jython. But I am stuck with Nullpointer Exception.

This is my Java code.

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.exec("import sys\nsys.path.append('myPath')\nimport jythonFirst");
PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("jythonFirst.printAndReturn");
PyObject result = someFunc.__call__();
String realResult = (String) result.__tojava__(String.class);
System.out.println(realResult);
```

Here 'someFunc' is getting null. So that on the next line when I am calling the python function, I am getting exception.

This is my Python code.

```
print ("I am in Python Program")

def printAndReturn(a):    
    print ("Printing Passed Value")
    print a
    return a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suspect your line is subtlety wrong:

```
PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("jythonFirst.printAndReturn");
```

[PythonInterpreter#get(String)](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) returns a variable from the local namespace. `jythonFirst` is in the local namepsace, but `printAndReturn` is under `jythonFirst`. So you need to get a reference to your module `jythonFirst`, and then from there get a reference to the `printAndReturn` function. E.g.,

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.exec("import sys\nsys.path.append('myPath')\nimport jythonFirst");

PyObject jythonFirst = interpreter.get("jythonFirst");
PyObject someFunc = jythonFirst.__getattr__(Py.newString("printAndReturn"));
PyObject result = someFunc.__call__();

String realResult = (String) result.__tojava__(String.class);
System.out.println(realResult);
```